This SG question can't be approved and published
I noticed in the timeline of this SG question that a few users had tried to approve and publish it, but it was still in the New status, so I figured I'd try to approve it as well (for science!). That... Didn't go well.
Attempting to approve this question yields an "An unexpected error occurred while performing review" error. Demonstration:

No error is logged in the console. This is the response that generates the error message:
{
    "Success": false,
    "ValidationFailure": false,
    "Message": "An unexpected error occurred while performing review",
    "WasReviewedSincePageLoad": false,
    "WasEditedSincePageLoad": false,
    "HasUserReachedDailyReviewLimit": false,
    "IsLockedForReview": false
}

This does generate a review history item, though:

What's going on here?

I wonder if one of the validators for live posts is failing, like the question has too much code or something that isn't being tested for in SG.

There was a similar case reported during the beta (link for people having access) but it was marked as status-norepro. This was the post where the issue had occured before if that's useful.

I already reported this here (marked as [status-review] by a staff member). Using the "Conditionally Approve with Minor Edits" option followed by approvind worked in my case.

Also what might have caused it is the author edits between originally posting the question to the SG and the first approval. What might fix it is either removing the backticks of the first codeblock (that shouldn't be a codeblock) or using "Minor Edits" and then publishing normally.
